# How to retrieve value from a form and insert into Modal Box using asp.net mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc 4.

I have one form that contains one text box and one preview button(If I will click on the preview button then one modal box will open ,one text box is there in the modal box) .After running the application ,I have to insert value in to the textbox ,after that when I will click on preview button that text box value should display in the modal box text box.

**Coding**
**index.cshtml**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<button id="modal-opener">preview</button>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="text" name="pasw" />

<div id="dialog-modal" title=" Basic Modal Dialog">
   <p>This is test</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" />   
</div>
```

**Homecontroller.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ModalPopUp.Controllers
  {
    public class HomeController : Controller
      {
        public ActionResult Index()
         {
          return View();
         }
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       <link href="~/content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       <script src="~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
      <script>
        $(function () {
           $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                modal:true,
                show:{
                duration:100
                    },
                hide: {
                duration: 1000
                  }
             });
          $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
             $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
          });
       });
       </script>
     </head>
   <body>
     @RenderBody()
     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
  </body>
</html>
```

Can any one help me out to solve this problem ?The value what I will insert into the text box that should display in modal box's text box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery would be sufficient.

```
 var val = $("input[name='username']").val();
 $("#dialog-modal").find("input[name='username']").val(val);
 $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1pn73ceq/)

Comment: will you tell me one thing,if i have <label id="username"> then how i can access in jquery ?

Comment: @Cool, use `#` when accessing element by id `$("#username")`